# CentOS force dnf to use mirrors of a specific location

Tags: centos, yum, repository, dnf, geolocation

Using CentOS 8.

I would like to force `dnf` to only use mirrors in the vicinity of a certain location without having to manually maintain a list of desirable mirrors. So I looked to modify the repo config files in `/etc/yum.repo.d/`.

Take `/etc/yum.repo.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo` for example, this is its default state:

```
[baseos]
name=CentOS Linux $releasever - BaseOS
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS&infra=$infra
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```

I would like to know if there is a parameter when querying `mirrorlist.centos.org` I can specify to filter by location, something like this:

```
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?country=us&other-params-ommitted
```

(`country=` I tried, didn't do anything)

I haven't been able to find any relevant documentation on the site's API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I dug a little deeper before posting this question and got the answer myself, so here it is.

I searched for "Centos mirrorlist API" and found the [code repository for the webservice](https://github.com/CentOS/mirrorlists-code). I dug into its source and found this piece of code [here](https://github.com/CentOS/mirrorlists-code/blob/master/frontend/isoredirect.py#L35-L58):

```py
  ip=request.remote_route[-1]
  cc=request.query.cc
  debug=request.query.debug
  remote_ip = ipaddr.IPAddress(ip)
  mirrorlistpage = "https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/"
  if branch == "altarch":
    mirrorlistpage = "https://www.centos.org/download/altarch-mirrors/"

  region = None
  if len(cc) == 5 and cc[2:3] == "-":
    country = cc[:2]
    region = cc[3:]
  elif len(cc) > 0:
    country = cc
  else:
    try:
      country = geodb.city(ip).country.iso_code.lower()
      if country == 'us' or country == 'ca':
        try:
          region = geodb.city(ip).subdivisions.most_specific.iso_code
        except:
          pass
    except:
      country = 'fallback'
```

It seems like the parameter is just `cc`. I tested with the following URLs and indeed got my desired mirrors:

- http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=BaseOS&cc=us
- http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=BaseOS&cc=cn

---

### Edit

It turns out I actually looked at the wrong file, which is a bit embarrassing

- [`isoredirect.py`](https://github.com/CentOS/mirrorlists-code/blob/master/frontend/isoredirect.py) is actually responsible for the ISO downloads page;
- [`ml.py`](https://github.com/CentOS/mirrorlists-code/blob/master/frontend/ml.py) is the one responsible for mirrorlist. I didn't look at it initially because I thought it stands for machine learning... Oh well.

I mean, I got to the correct answer though, just via an inaccurate process. `cc` is also used in `ml.py` and does pretty much the exact same thing.

Comment: Nice find. The `cc` is the `Country Code` so which makes sense.